# Ce lundi versus ce lundi-là

Tags: grammaire

Sorry, I could not search for a rule. My google-fu has failed me.

I am wondering what is the difference between ***ce lundi*** and ***ce lundi-la***.

The phrase that prompted the question is:

> Léa avait fermé son magasin plus tôt ce lundi-là.

Is this "là" obligatory? Does it change the meaning?

Answer (score 3):

*Là* is used to state this is about that precise Monday. The Monday we are talking about. It's necessarily a different day than "today", it is in the past or in the future and usually not very close to the present.

Without *là*, *ce lundi* means the Monday close to the current day<sup>1</sup>, usually next Monday but that can also be last Monday depending on the context (especially the verb tense) and of course the current day itself if it is already Monday.

We use the same construction with *année*.

*Cette année* : If the sentence uses a non narrative present, this year: now in 2021.

*[Cette année-là](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1sgNtn-sOQ)* : that year, it might be 2019, 1962, 2050, any year but not 2021.

In the sentence you wrote, the ***-là*** is not obligatory. It adds something but can be skipped:

> *Léa avait fermé son magasin plus tôt ce lundi.*

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>This current day is not necessarily today. For example if the text describes events happening in the past, that current day is relative to the time of the story.</sub>

Comment: @Lambie Didn't I already write *Cette année: [...] **this** year; **Cette année là**: **that year***?

Comment: Ok, I will change my comment. Due to the difficulty of this issue for French speakers in English, it becomes somewhat tedious **for me** to read through the answers. Let's just leave it at that. Ce lundi sans plus veut dire en anglais: This [coming] Monday. {Il est dimanche aujourd'hui}. Et je te dis: Ce mercredi j'irai à la piscine. This [coming] Wednesday, I'm going to the pool.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, je comprends. Je n'arrête pas de confondre *this* et *that* si je ne fais pas très attention, et même dans ce cas, il m'arrive encore souvent de me tromper. La différence est très marquée en anglais entre *this* et *that* alors qu'en français, on peut très bien dire indifféremment *viens ici* ou *viens là*. On a aussi les paires *ceci/cela* et *celui-ci/celui-là* qui n'ont pas de différence très significative pour nous et donc *ce/cet/cette* qui sont aussi bien *this* que *that*.

Comment: @Lambie *Ce lundi* peut aussi vouloir dire *lundi dernier*. C'est le temps du verbe utilisé qui permet de distinguer les deux cas.

Comment: Oui, c'est ça. Merci de ton honnêteté. On entend souvent la phrase: Est-qu'il est là? pour différents contextes semer la confusion:  question au téléphone (Is he there?) ou tu arrives à la porte (Is he here?). Ce n'est pas facile, je sais.

Answer (score 0):

"Ce lundi" means "a particular monday" in the past or "this day" when the speaker is speaking on a given Monday; it can also mean "this coming Monday", but more usual is the expression "lundi prochain" or "[le lundi qui vient](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22le%20lundi%20qui%20vient%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)".

*In the past - "-là" can be added*

([ref. 1853](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Causeries_du_Lundi/HjkPAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22ce+lundi%22&pg=PA33&printsec=frontcover)) Ce lundi , au sortir de la séance de l'Institut , il dina à Paris  et retourna coucher à Saint - Cloud . Le lendemain , mardi au matin , le roi le fit

(réf. 2011](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Symfonia/nIi6BgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22ce+lundi%22&pg=PT199&printsec=frontcover)) Pourtant, en ce lundi 16 novembre – journée à première vue on ne peut plus détestable – un miracle se produisit : Alice Sycomore était de bonne humeur.

([réf. 2018](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_inconnue_de_la_Cit%C3%A9_Baby/OIAEEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22ce+lundi%22&pg=PT78&printsec=frontcover)) Quelle était la raison du passage de votre ami, ce lundi, la veille de sa mort ? J'avais besoin de ses conseils à propos de l'un de mes pur-sang.

([réf. 2012](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Mai_le_joli_mai/ngbERlw7-n8C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22ce+lundi%22&pg=PT88&printsec=frontcover)) Est-ce ce lundi ou le lundi suivant que collège et lycée Jean-Moulin ont été fermés ? Je ne m'en souviens pas. Peut—être bien que ce fut le lundi 27.

([réf. 2017](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_Disparus/RtoyDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22ce+lundi%22&pg=PT120&printsec=frontcover)) Car le Joe à qui Shmiel Jäger écrivait, en ce lundi d'autrefois, le « cher Cousin » auquel il adressait cette requête mortifiée, était un Mittelmark ...

*This day - "là" cannot be added*

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Memoires_du_President_Henault/E61y6E8ZRyYC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22ce+lundi%22&pg=PA323&printsec=frontcover) ) Voilà la lettre que je lui écrivis le lundi , après la messe rouge : A Pontoise ce lundi au soir . « Nous sommes arrivés ici hier à quatre heures , après ...

([réf. 2013](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Recueil_Nouveaux_Talents_Harlequin_HQN/3eI7AAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22ce+lundi%22&pg=PT36&printsec=frontcover)) Mais ce lundi a été la pire journée de ma vie. Depuis mon départ ce matin, alors que tu dormais encore, si belle sur l'oreiller couvert de tes cheveux

([réf. 1867](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Revue_bleue/Vg05AQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22ce+lundi%22&pg=PA632&printsec=frontcover)) Il est daté : « Chaillot , ce lundi à trois heures . » M. Lavallée ajoute entre parenthèses

"Là" is used to reinforce the idea of a past time or of a time to come.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ce)) − − [Pour indiquer avec netteté un temps éloigné] Ce ...-là.
> ♦ En ce temps-là, à ce moment-là, ce jour-là, ce soir-là
> ♦ De l'état d'âme qui, cette lointaine année-là, n'avait été pour moi qu'une longue torture, rien ne subsistait. Proust, Le Temps retrouvé,1922, p. 695
> **Rem.** La lang. littér. omet souvent la particule renforçative *-là*. À ce moment, à cet instant, ce soir, cette année.

- (*future*) Le lundi que vous avez choisi pour le rendez-vous dans deux mois ne convient pas, ce lundi-là est le lundi de Pâques ; il faudrait choisir un autre jour. (user LPH's example)

Comment: today is the term, not this day. And ce lundi is this Monday. So, in English, if it's Sunday, the next day can be called: This Monday. If the speaker is speaking on a Monday, the speaker would say: today.

Comment: @Lambie https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/this%20day

Comment: When the speaker is referring to Monday and it is Monday, we say: today or Today, Monday. You can't use a thesaurus to prove usage.

Comment: This day [5] in June 1944 was D-Day, also known as the Normandy landings.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, with or without the lá changes which Monday is being referred to:

- Léa avait fermé son magasin plus tôt ce lundi-là.
- Lea had closed her shop earlier **[on] that Monday**.

VERSUS

- Léa avait fermé son magasin plus tôt ce lundi-ci. [emphasis on this one]
- Lea had closed her shop earlier **this** Monday. [the last Monday that occurred on the calendar]

Please note: this could also be said ce lundi, meaning this Monday, without any particular emphasis.

[this Monday with a verb in the past means this past Monday and cannot refer to a future Monday].

The ce...-lá is used to refer to "this/that" spatial or time feature in French with regard to the speaker. It contrasts with ce [noun]-ci.

For example: **Ce** chien-**ci** = **This dog** [here]

**Ce** chien-**là** = **That** dog [there].

*The important point is that the only way to make the distinction of the proximity or distance of the speaker to something is by using ce [noun] -là and ce [noun] -ci.* Whereas in English, this or that is usually enough.

The Larousse gives this explanation for **là** used in this way:

8. L'insistance avec les adjectifs démonstratifs ce, cet, cette, ces (joint au nom par un trait d'union) : Cet homme-là. Ces maisons-là.
   That man [there] or These houses [here]

In other words: "lá" is used to show emphasis with the demonstrative adjectives ce, cet, cette and ces by joining them to the noun with a hyphen. This is because has no single word for that. For that house, that car, that boy, you have to use ce...-là. Cette maison-là, ce garçon-là, cet voiture-là. And of course, this can be plural: ces maisons-là. Those houses.

And the Larousse says this about **ci**:

ci
adverbe

(latin ecce, voici, et hic, ici)

Souligne la proximité (par opposition à là), à la suite d'un pronom démonstratif ou d'un nom déterminé par un adjectif démonstratif, auquel il est lié par un trait d'union : Viens de ce côté-ci de la rue.

[ci in the Larousse Dictionary](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ci/15944)

It underscores proximity (as opposed to *là* [for distance away from]), after a demonstrative pronoun or noun modified by a demonstrative adjective to which it is linked by a hyphen: Come to this side of the street.

[In Spanish, the equivalent is este/aquel and in Portuguese esse/aquele]